# Batching and queuing wcf requests

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service using a TCP binding. I would like to batch and queue my dataservice requests from the client side. Is it even possible? If yes, then can you please explain how. It would be nice of you if you can give an example or link.

Comment: I dont really get "queue my dataservice request from the client side". Does it mean you want to put service calls in a queue, then defer their calls ?

Comment: What i really want to achieve is that I may be able to group a no. of requests, group them in an order and send them all in one single request to server and server executes them in the same order.

Comment: see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e016338-f38a-46d5-8105-29ad50480866/batch-processing-in-wcf?forum=wcf